# Codeigniter in shared ssl

Tags: codeigniter, ssl, shared

I am not able to get codeigniter to work on my shared ssl url.
for example, on
https://nimrod.eukhosting.net/~nadavwei/myatar.co.cc/aaa
i get a 404 error
aaa is just a demo controller that should echo test

only the homepage - with no controller in the url - works
https://nimrod.eukhosting.net/~nadavwei/myatar.co.cc/

btw, i am using .htaccess

thanks

Comment: In CI, a tilde `~` is not a valid character in URLs

Comment: it is a valid charcter see http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/security.html (2.02)

Comment: My bad, really sorry, I just realised one of my CI project is using `~` in URLs.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your provider is disabling  `.htaccess` for the https server.

I am able to see your website here: https://nimrod.eukhosting.net/~nadavwei/myatar.co.cc/index.php/categories/26

But it won't work here: https://nimrod.eukhosting.net/~nadavwei/myatar.co.cc/categories/26

My guess is that their setup allows or disallows `.htaccess` based on the virtual domain, and since you are not using your virtual domain, it is being disabled.  You should contact your hosting provider and see if they know or can provide more information.

You can also double check your .htaccess file, in case there is something about it specifying the virtual domain.

Also, as an FYI, you are going to have to modify your CodeIgniter configuration so that it dynamically the full path and turns on or off the `index.php` part of your URL based on whether or not the user is arriving via HTTPS:

```
$is_https = !empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']);
$config['base_url'] = $is_https ?
        'https://nimrod.eukhosting.net/~nadavwei/myatar.co.cc/' :
        'http://myatar.co.cc/';

$config['index_page'] = $is_https ? 'index.php' : '';
```

This should toggle the modes as necessary.

Comment: https://nimrod.eukhosting.net/~nadavwei/myatar.co.cc/index.php/categories/26 actually shows the homepage
I think this is because .htaccess:
  #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
  #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends   
  #the request to index.php